# Sinc function definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have seen answers to similar questions that reference a Si(x) function as a solution to the integral of sinc(x). Most of these questions have infinite upper or lower limits, though. I am interested in the definite integral of the sinc-like function like below.

$$
\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi r}{R})}{r}dr
$$

Explanations for the use of Si(x) lead me in circles. Could anyone explain if Si(x) is necessary here and how it is used.

Comment: This one is just a sinus, not a cardinal sinus, there is no $r$ at denominator...

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to have $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ here. That is why this special function is defined :)

Comment: Sorry I am unfamiliar with Si(x). Would this integral just become Si(pi)?

Comment: Yes, it's value is simply $\operatorname{Si}(\pi)$, independent of $R$.

Answer (score -1):

Although your function does not look immediately like a sinc, it can be re-writte as follows:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi r}{R})}{r}dr = \int_{0}^{R}\frac{\frac{\pi}{R}\,\sin(\frac{\pi r}{R})}{\frac{\pi}{R}\,r}dr = \frac{\pi}{R}\int_{0}^{R}\mathrm{sinc}(\frac{\pi r}{R})\,dr
\end{equation}

With substitution $u = \frac{\pi r}{R} \Rightarrow du/dr = \pi/R \Leftrightarrow dr = (R/\pi) du$ and adapating the integration boundaries to $u(r=0) = 0; u(r=R) = \pi$, this integral can easily be solved as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\pi}{R}\int_{0}^{R}\mathrm{sinc}(\frac{\pi r}{R})\,dr &= \frac{\pi}{R}\frac{R}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{sinc}(u)\,du = \int_{0}^{\pi} \mathrm{sinc}(u)\,du\\
&= (Si(\pi) - Si(0)) + C = Si(\pi) + C
\end{split}
\end{equation}

with $\mathrm{sinc}(x) = \sin(x)/x$ and Si(x) denoting the sine integral